# iOS properties of a singleton object are always nil after being set value to it when executing unit test

Tags: ios, unit-testing, properties, null, cocoapods

my property is always nil when running unit test.
I have a private pod which is linked with Main target and MainTest target. There is a singleton class, called SingletonClass, in my own private pod, this class includes three private properties and are being set a string in init method like the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *privateProperty;

- (instance)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _privateProperty = [someClass classMethod]; // [someClass classMethod] returns a string value from plist
    }
    return self;
}
```

When I'm executing the unit test (command + u), after the line `_privateProperty = [someClass classMethod]` executed, _privateProperty is nil.

But when I'm executing the main target, _privateProperty is just fine.

I've spent almost a week on this problem, if you have any ideas, please let me know, thanks.

P.S. I'm using Xcode 6.4 and Expecta & Specta to implement my test cases.